# How to retain a hover state when hovering a sibling?

Tags: html, css, hover

```
// HTML
<nav _v-2e9e2f12="">
  <ul _v-2e9e2f12="">
    <li _v-2e9e2f12="">
      <a _v-2e9e2f12=""></a>
    </li>
    <ul tabindex="-1" _v-0078ee36="" _v-2e9e2f12="" class="menu" style="top: 30px; left: 35px">
      <li _v-0078ee36=""><a _v-0078ee36="">Split up</a></li>
      <li _v-0078ee36=""><a _v-0078ee36="">Split down</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</nav>

// CSS
nav > ul li[_v-2e9e2f12]:hover {
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-transform: translate(3px);
  transform: translate(3px);
}
```

Now, I want to retain that hover state when `<ul tabindex="-1" _v-0078ee36="">` is hovered.

How to accomplish that?

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u868Lazf/1/

(Note: I'm also open to jQuery solutions)

Comment: There are no parent selectors in CSS so you have to use JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect but a solution:

jQuery:

```
$('ul li[_v-0078ee36]:first-child').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('li[_v-2e9e2f12]').addClass('up');
},function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('li[_v-2e9e2f12]').removeClass('up');
});
$('ul li[_v-0078ee36]:last-child').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('li[_v-2e9e2f12]').addClass('down');
},function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('li[_v-2e9e2f12]').removeClass('down');
});
```

CSS:

```
nav > ul li[_v-2e9e2f12].up {
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-3px);
  transform: translate(0,-3px);
}

nav > ul li[_v-2e9e2f12].down {
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,3px);
  transform: translate(0,3px);
}
```

You should use less confusing class names and some more specific one so you can find the one you need easier.